# wxPython Sliders that influence each other

Tags: python, wxpython, sliders

I am writing a program based on this [matplotlib slider example](http://wiki.wxpython.org/MatplotlibFourierDemo). Now I want to create a third slider that acts as a parent slider and changes both sliders at the same time. Does anybody know a good tutorial on that topic? Or a way how to implement it in this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fairly easy to do.  **Catch the EVT_SCROLL** events issued from the "parent" slider, and when these occur, have the handler **call SetValue(position)** for each of the two "child" sliders.  This way, you can set them based on whatever algorithm you choose.